# Popular symbols for disjointness relation of two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there any standard or popular symbol to indicate that two set A and B are disjoint?

Of course, it can be described by:

[image]

**But it is still way too long.** Is there any popular symbol for the disjointness relation `R` such that we can write as below?

[image]

Comment: Not in general, no. I have seen occasional nonce usages, but any such notation would have to be defined, and unless there were a very good reason for using it, it would most likely be a bit of a burden on the reader.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: updated, thanks for correcting!

Comment: If you define in the text the relation of "disjointness" then you can use it after. I would use, by example, the perpendicular symbol $\bot$ in analogy with many other applications. But anyway to me $A\cap B=\emptyset$ is enough short.

Comment: @ BrianM.Scott, Masacroso: it is not common used in general textbooks, but I see quite often in scientific papers, the disjointness of two set is required (logic and computer science). Thus, I think it is still good to have a standard notation to describe it.

Comment: Write $A)\>(B$, or similar.